# How can I append and prepend something to all post hyperlinks without using ::before or ::after? PHP hook solution?

Tags: functions, css, hooks, links

I have links on my website that use the before and after pseudo elements to style them.

I would like to append and prepend brackets to all links. Like this:

> This is an example of a paragraph in a post. It would look like this but when it comes to a hyperlink it would look like [[ this ]](http://google.com).

You see how I put a bracket before and after the link? I want to do that, but I can't using the before after elements because they're already being used for something else. surely there's a way to do this in functions.php or something right? I know that Advanced Custom Fields has a way to append any custom field you make, so it seems like it shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: What are they already being used for?

Comment: I'm using the Before pseudo class to do a fake underline like the second one on this page: https://tympanus.net/Development/InlineAnchorStyles/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this with a WordPress hook would be difficult to do reliably.

But it's straightforward with jQuery and some CSS.

```
jQuery('a').wrap('<div class="brackets"/>');

.brackets:before {
  content: "\005B";
}
.brackets:after {
  content: "\005D";
}
```

Comment: Would it? Because I found this:

`function wpdev_before_after($content) {
    $beforecontent = 'This goes before the content. Isn\'t that awesome!';
    $aftercontent = 'And this will come after, so that you can remind them of something, like following you on Facebook for instance.';
    $fullcontent = $beforecontent . $content . $aftercontent;

    return $fullcontent;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wpdev_before_after');`

And it seems all I really need to do there is find an appropriate filter for the links inside the post right? Is that not built in? I'm new and haven't made plugins

Comment: To make sure it's clear, I know that function won't work, but I just need a filter for the links instead of for the_content right?

I'm trying to implement your solution right now. I'm also a little worried that it might be bad for SEO? Make internal linking hard for crawlers to follow?

Comment: There is no filter for links, links are just text within your content.

Comment: Okay cool. Also I got the jquery function and styling thing to work. Only change I made was I used wrapInner() instead of wrap so that the outermost tag would be the anchor tag (which is important for semantic reasons I believe). Thank you guys!